# How to add a custom CMS block with a shopware app

Tags: shopware

We want to add a custom cms-block to the shopware backend which can then be added to the layout. While I can do so pretty easy with a plugin it does not work similar within an app.

In the documentation it's mentioned that any javascript under `Resource/administration` will be ignored so the plugin way won't work as it needs the `main.js` file. But I can't find a reference online how to solve this.

Does any someone knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Currently that is not possible with an app, but we are actively working on that feature. It is on our [public roadmap](https://www.shopware.com/de/roadmap/) under the term `AppSystem 3.0`.

From the roadmap:

> This will include the option to add menu entries via an app, open the actual app inside a modal or enrich the CMS with an app.
>
> Also, it will be made possible to build payment apps.

Please refer to the roadmap for further updates on the timeline.